# $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I would like to prove that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. Using the hint provided in Reed & Simon's book, I was able to show that:

1. the set of simple functions on $[a,b]$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$
2. the set of step functions on $[a,b]$ is dense in the set of simple functions on $[a,b]$.

Next, I would like to show that $C([a,b])$ is dense in the set of step functions on $[a,b]$, so that I can conclude that $C([a,b])$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$. Then, using this fact, I would like to show that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable. This is where I am having some trouble.

To prove the denseness of $C([a,b])$ in the set of step functions on $[a,b]$, note that by definition a step function is defined on a disjoint union of open intervals. Consider two consecutive open intervals, $(a_l, a_r)$ and $(b_l, b_r)$. We can construct a continuous function that agrees with the simple function on $(a_l, a_r-\epsilon/2) \cup(b_l+\epsilon/2, b_r)$, and construct a linear function connecting the points at $a_r-\epsilon/2$ and $b_l+\epsilon/2$. Since the support of this line can be made arbitrarily small we will obtain the result.

Based on the above, to prove that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is separable it will suffice to prove that $C([a,b])$ has a countable dense subset. One approach I thought of was to use polynomials with rational coefficients. However, this would invoke the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, which does not appear until later in the book so I'm trying to avoid it. I will also have to extend the domain of $C([a,b])$ to $C(\mathbb{R})$, but I think this can be achieved by taking the countable union
$$\bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty [n, n+1].$$

Assuming my ideas are correct, I am have some trouble making these arguments rigorous.

---

EDIT: Upon thinking about it further and taking a look at a few other books, I came up with the following. Let $f$ be a step function on $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon > 0$. By Lusin's theorem there exists a continuous function $g$ that agrees with $f$ except on a set of measure $\epsilon$. Then
$$\|f - g\|_{L_2} = \int_{[a,b]}|f-g|^2d\mu = \int_{\{x \in [a,b]: f(x) \neq g(x)\}} |f-g|^2 d\mu \\\leq \epsilon \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f|^2 \rightarrow 0$$
I am unsure of the above since Lusin's theorem only holds for functions with compact support, but what if our step function do not have compact support? This might be a problem when extending our domain from $[a,b]$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$. Also the above doesn't use anything about step functions, so couldn't it have been applied to any $f \in L^2([a,b])$?

However, if this is correct than I have shown that $C([a,b])$ is dense in $L^2([a,b])$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, the polynomials are also dense in $L^2([a,b])$. Countability follows by considering polynomials with rational coefficients (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). Hence $L^2([a,b])$ is separable. The only thing remaining is to extent this result to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Notice that since
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\cdots) d\mu = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[-n,n]} (\cdots) d\mu $$
all our previous results hold for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and so we are done. Does this last step need to be justified any further?

Comment: C([a,b]) is not dense in the set of step functions. It is not even contained in it!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Have I misinterpreted the problem from Reed & Simon? It says that "Show that any step function can approximated arbitrarily closely (in the $L^2$ sense) by a continuous function".

Comment: That claim is true, but it certainly does.not imply that the continuous functions are dense in the space of step functions, because the latter does not contain the former. It is true that the space of continuous functions is contains on the closure of the space of continuous ones, for example, but that is quite a different statement!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see now, thank you for pointing that out. Does that affect any part of my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas are fine. And indeed you can apply your argument directly via Lusin and avoid simple and step functions.

When your domain is $\mathbb R$, you first show that the functions with finite-measure support are dense, and then apply your argument.

About separability, if you already know that step functions are dense, show that the step functions with rational coefficients and rational endpoints in their intervals are dense in the step functions.

Finally, from a more advanced point of view (maybe you don't know what the words mean, but some day you will): one can prove that $L^2[a,b]$ is separable rather directly by showing that it has a countable orthonormal basis (here we see $L^2$ as a Hilbert space).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not think to use the fact that a Hilbert space is separable iff it has a countable orthonormal basis which was probably what the book had in mind. Based on your suggestion, when the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, can we show that functions with finite-measure support are dense as follows: for $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ let $f_n = f\chi_{[-n. n]}$. Then using the dominated convergence theorem, $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Lastly, how would we show that the step functions with rational coefficients and rational endpoints are dense? I tried this approach when working on the problem but the issue I had was that if a step function is given by $ \sum c_i (a_i, b_i)$, the $c_i, a_i, b_i$ all converge independently. How would one work around that?

Comment: You are integrating, so small intervals should be negligible if chosen small enough. It might be simpler to do it in two steps: first go to rational coefficients, and then to rational endpoints. If $(c,d)\subset(a,b)$, then $$\|1_{[a,b]}-1_{[c,d]}\|_2=\sqrt{c+d-a-b}.$$ And, on a separate note, approximating with $f\,1_{[-n,n]}$ is the standard way to do that.

Comment: So because we are integrating the small initial interval that results from the terms converging at different rates is negligible?

Comment: Yes, you can choose your rationals very very close to the end points, so that the total contribution to the norm is as small as you want.

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help!

Comment: You are very welcome!